# Sine Wave with Oscillating Half-wavelength

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, wave-equation

What's the equation of a sine wave where the length of $\frac{λ}{2}$ oscillates, say between 2 and 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by a constant inside the brackets stretches in the $x$ direction

e.g. $y=sin (2x)$ has wavelength 180 degrees instead of 360 degrees.

If we work in radians you'll need $sin({\pi} x)$ to make a wavelength of 2 and half the wavelength will be 1.  By chance, since the wave repeats, it's also between 2 and 3.

Here is a graph of it on Desmos.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aqfzl4g1p4

Comment: Thank you. But I think there is a misunderstanding here: I want the length of mu wave's $\frac{λ}{2}$ to oscillate from 2 to 3 and back to 2.... every $\frac{λ}{2}$, that is, every $π$. In other words, the half wavelength will not be constant like the wave shown in the graph. Thanks gain!